# Alternate to fallbackToDestructiveMigration()?

Tags: realm, realm-java

I don't want to provide a migration script while changing table schema in realm java. Also, app should not crash and all the previous data should be erased or truncated something similar to [fallbackToDestructiveMigration()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/RoomDatabase.Builder#fallbacktodestructivemigration) as room dose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realm provides `RealmConfiguration.Builder().deleteIfMigrationNeeded()...`, where `deleteIfMigrationNeeded()` does exactly what you are looking for.